# Unhide nodes when using visOptions nodesIdSelection

Tags: r, shiny, visnetwork

I want to hide all but the first 10 nodes to start when using visnetwork in a shiny app. When the node is selected using the *nodesIdSelection* dropdown, I want to unhide the node and show the relations. Below is as far as I've gotten with a test example.

```
library(visNetwork)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

getvisNetworkNodes = function(nodes){
  purrr::map_df(nodes,function(node){
    dplyr::tibble(name = names(node),values = node) %>%
      dplyr::filter(!name %in% c('bodyHiddenColor','isHardToRead')) %>%
      dplyr::mutate_all(unlist) %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = values)
  })
}

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:15, label = paste("Label", 1:15),
                    group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE),
                    physics = T, 
                    hidden = F)
nodes[11:15,"hidden"] = T
nodes[11:15,"physics"] = F

edges <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                    to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$networkGraph <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges, 
               height = "100%", width = "100%",
               main = "") %>%
      visOptions(nodesIdSelection = T)
  })
  
  # make sure selected node is not hidden
  shiny::observeEvent(input$networkGraph_selected, {
    nodeID = input$networkGraph_selected
    print(nodeID)
    if(!is.null(nodeID) && nodeID != ""){
      shiny::observe({
        visNetwork::visNetworkProxy("networkGraph") %>%
          visNetwork::visGetNodes(input = "networkGraph_nodes")
        nodes = getvisNetworkNodes(input$networkGraph_nodes)
        print(nodes)
        nodes[which(nodes$id == nodeID),] %<>% mutate(hidden = 'FALSE')
        visNetwork::visNetworkProxy("networkGraph") %>%
          visNetwork::visUpdateNodes(nodes = nodes)
      })
    }
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("networkGraph") 
)

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

edit: removed session$ns used in module (forgot to take it out)

Answer (score 0):

(Edited so the network does not redraw) This is the only workaround I could come up with. I used a reactive object to update the values of the nodes which then redraws the network. <strike>Ideally the network would not have to be redrawn each time.</strike>

```
library(visNetwork)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rvals = reactiveValues(nodes = data.frame(id = 1:15, label = paste("Label", 1:15),
                                            group = sample(LETTERS[1:3],15,replace = T),
                                             hidden = sample(c(T,F),15,replace = T)),
                         edges = data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                                             to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1))
  output$networkGraph <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(rvals$nodes, rvals$edges, 
               height = "100%", width = "100%",
               main = "") %>%
      visOptions(nodesIdSelection = T)
  })
  
  myVisProxy = visNetworkProxy("networkGraph")
  
  observeEvent(input$networkGraph_selected,{
    if(!is.null(input$networkGraph_selected) && input$networkGraph_selected != ""){
      df = rvals$nodes
      print(df)
      df[input$networkGraph_selected,'hidden'] = FALSE
      visUpdateNodes(myVisProxy, nodes = df)
    }
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("networkGraph")
)

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```